# Syntax match array of builtin types

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a syntax file for Solidity files.

Solidity has several built-in types, such as `uint8`, `uint16`, ..., `uint256`, `bytes1`, `bytes2`, ... `bytes32`, etc.

One can have arrays for pretty much all types in the language.

Arrays can be either fixed or dynamic:

```
uint256[3] fixedArray;
uint256[] dynamicArray;
```

I have rules like this for every built-in type:

```
syn keyword solBuiltinType       uint uint8 uint16 uint24 uint32 uint40 uint48 uint56 uint64 uint72 uint80 uint88 uint96 uint104 uint112 uint120 uint128 uint136 uint144 uint152 uint160 uint168 uint178 uint184 uint192 uint200 uint208 uint216 uint224 uint232 uint240 uint248 uint256
```

I tried to append the following rules:

```
syn keyword solBuiltinType       skipempty skipwhite nextgroup=solBuiltinTypeArray
syn region solBuiltinTypeArray   contained start='\[' end='\]'
hi def link solBuiltinTypeArray  Type
```

However it's not picking up the syntax color:

[image: bad-hl]